# Python: Dynamic "from" import

Tags: python

So i'm trying to turn a bunch of "from x import x" statements, that look like this:

```
from class_foo import class_foo
```

into something dynamic.  I'm trying to pass a path to a directory and have it import all of the modules therein.

```
def dynamicImport(dirPath):
    filez = os.listdir(dirPath)
    for file in filez:
        if "class" in file:
            oname = file[:-3] #cut off the file extension, trivial

            imp_statement = "from " + oname + " import " + oname
            #when I print imp_statement, I can verify it's being concatenated correctly

            exec(imp_statement)
```

When I run this function and pass it a path, the statement strings are being created properly and it **produces no errors**, yet then later I'll try to access one of the imported objects, and this happens:

```
foo = class_foo()

NameError: name 'class_foo' is not defined
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You say that you intend to pass a **path to** a file, but the code shown here will only get the actual file **names** - because that's what you'll get from `os.listdir`. If you want to import based on the name, but use Python's lookup mechanism to find the file, that will work very differently from importing from a path that is explicitly specified (even if relative). I have put duplicate links for both relevant approaches.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're `exec`ing your import statement in your function's local namespace, so that's where the names are defined. This namespace goes away when the function ends, leaving you with nothing. What you probably want is something like `exec imp_statement in globals()`.

Why not just use [`__import__()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__) instead of string-munging? Then you get a reference to your module. You can then fish out the class reference using `getattr()` on the module object and insert that into `globals()` (or just pass a dictionary back to the caller, who can then do `globals().update()` with it).

```
import sys, os

def getClasses(directory):
    classes = {}
    oldcwd = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(directory)   # change working directory so we know import will work
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            modname = filename[:-3]
            classes[modname] = getattr(__import__(modname), modname)
    os.setcwd(oldcwd)
    return classes

globals().update(getClasses(r"C:\plugin_classes"))
```

Something like that. Or rather than updating `globals()` with your modules, which could clobber a global variable you care about, just leave the classes in the dictionary and reference them from there:

```
classes = getClasess(r"C:\plugin_classes")
for clas in classes.itervalues():
    instance = clas(1, 2, 3)       # instantiate
    instance.dosomething_cool(42)  # call method
```

Comment: You can use the `fromlist` keyword arg and supply a list of the attributes you're interested in retrieving rather than using `getattr`.

Comment: Wow, thanks. `__import__` confused the heck out of me, as I didn't realize you could use `getattr` with it to extract the class from the module itself.  Thanks a million!

Comment: @mvanveen: The `fromlist` keyword arg doesn't really seem to do what you'd want it to do here, unfortunately. It still gives me a reference to the module.

Answer (score 9):

Python >= 2.7 has [importlib](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/importlib.html) (you can [pip install importlib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/importlib) to use importlib in earlier versions of python)

```
module = importlib.import_module("path.to.module")
MyClass = module.MyClass
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your directory structure looks like this:

```
./   <- you are here
- main.py
- my_package/
    - __init__.py
    - my_module.py
```

and you want to dynamically import `my_module.py`, to use some of its functions, classes, whatever.  Then, using `importlib`, you can use the following code in `main.py`:

```py
import importlib

pack = "my_package"
mod = "my_module"

module = importlib.import_module("." + mod, pack)
# or, alternatively
module = importlib.import_module(".".join(pack, mod))

module.func("hello") # if my_package/my_module.py defines function "func"
obj = module.MyClass("world") # if my_package/my_module.py defines class "MyClass"
```

Answer (score -2):

It's been a long time since I've worked with Python.  But I think your problem might lay in the fact that "oname" is a string.  The line  `from class_foo import class_foo` is not a string.   One painstaking option would be to have your code make a whole new .py file that would have all of the imports.  So you would write all of your current file plus the new imports to, basically, a text file ending in .py

Answer (score -3):

Take a look at the [__import__](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__) function

Comment: Please take a look at adding example code and not just providing links