# Python: Dynamicaly imported module fails when first created, then succeeds

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic, python-import

I have a template engine named [Contemplate](https://github.com/foo123/Contemplate) which has implementations for `php`, `node/js` and `python`.

All work fine except lately the python implementation gives me some issues. Specificaly the problem appears when first parsing a template and creating the template python code which is then dynamically imported as a module. When template is already created everything works fine but when template needs to be parsed and saved to disk and THEN imported it raises an error eg

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blah blah'`

(**note** this error appears to be random, it is not always sure that it will be raised, many times it works even if template is created just before importing, other times it fails and then if ran again with template already created it succeeds)

Is there any way I can bypass this issue, maybe add a delay between saving a parsed template and then importing as module or somethig  else?

The code to import the module (the parsed template which is now a python class) is below:

```
def import_tpl( filename, classname, cacheDir, doReload=False ):
    # http://www.php2python.com/wiki/function.import_tpl/
    # http://docs.python.org/dev/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821104/python-dynamic-instantiation-from-string-name-of-a-class-in-dynamically-imported

    #_locals_ = {'Contemplate': Contemplate}
    #_globals_ = {'Contemplate': Contemplate}
    #if 'execfile' in globals():
    #    # Python 2.x
    #    execfile(filename, _globals_, _locals_)
    #    return _locals_[classname]
    #else:
    #    # Python 3.x
    #    exec(read_file(filename), _globals_, _locals_)
    #    return _locals_[classname]

    # http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html
    # http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__
    # http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108628/python-dynamic-from-import
    # also: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/473888-lazy-module-imports/
    # using import instead of execfile, usually takes advantage of Python cached compiled code

    global _G
    getTplClass = None
    # add the dynamic import path to sys
    basename = os.path.basename(filename)
    directory = os.path.dirname(filename)
    os.sys.path.append(cacheDir)
    os.sys.path.append(directory)
    currentcwd = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(directory)   # change working directory so we know import will work

    if os.path.exists(filename):

        modname = basename[:-3]  # remove .py extension
        mod = __import__(modname)
        if doReload: reload(mod) # Might be out of date
        # a trick in-order to pass the Contemplate super-class in a cross-module way
        getTplClass = getattr( mod, '__getTplClass__' )

    # restore current dir
    os.chdir(currentcwd)
    # remove the dynamic import path from sys
    del os.sys.path[-1]
    del os.sys.path[-1]

    # return the tplClass if found
    if getTplClass:  return getTplClass(Contemplate)
    return None
```

**Note** the engine creates a `__init__.py` file in `cacheDir` if it is not there already.

If needed I can change the `import_tpl` function to sth else I dont mind.

Python tested is `python 3.6` on `windows` but I dont think this is a platform-specific issue.

To test the issue you can download the `github` repository (linked above) and run the `/tests/test.py` test after clearing all cached templates from `/tests/_tplcache/` folder

UPDATE:

I am thinking of adding a `while` loop with some counter in `import_tpl` that catches the error raised if any and retries a specified amount of times until it succeeds to import the module. But I am also wondering if this is a good solution or there is something else I am missing here..

UPDATE (20/02/2019):

Added a loop to retry a specified amount of times plus a small delay of 1 sec if initially failed to import template module (see online repository code), but still it raises same error sometimes when templates are first created before being imported. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Right, if you use a "while" loop with to handle exceptions would be one way.

```
while True:
    try:
        #The module importing
        break
    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        print("NOPE! Module not found")
```

If it works for some other, an not other "module" files, the likely suspect is the template files the template files themselves.

Comment: any idea why this happens and why at random, sometimes it happens sometimes not, with same template. Especially if a template extends another template, this is wghere i've seen it most. Can it be a disk issue, or is it a python issue?

Comment: I have already added a while loop which retries to import the module a specified amount of times then returns if it cannot (have also updated github repository). But I am wondering if this is the best solution I can find..

Comment: Hmmm, git cloning the repo now, allow me some time to inspect and Ill see what I come up with. Hopefully, you'll get your answer before I do lol.

Comment: Still I get same error even after I added code to retry a specificed amount of times (3 for example) AND I added a small delay of 1 sec before retrying. Any new thoughts..?