# Is there a way to auto-import all the models in my folder when loading __init__.py?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, init

In my Python 3.9, Django 3.2 project, I have this general folder structure

```
- manage.py
+ cbapp
    + models
        - __init__.py
        - vendor.py
        - user_preferences.py
```

In my **init**.py file, I have all my model entries listed out ...

```
from .vendor import Vendor
from .user_preferences import UserPreferences
...
```

Each model class, e.g. Vendor, has this general sturcture

```
from django.db import models

class Vendor(models.Model): 
    ...
```

Every time I add a new model I have to add a line into my **init**.py file.  Is there any way I can write my **init**.py file so that it will just auto-import new files I add into my models directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is some fancy dynamic imports, such as [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11108712/2800876).

If your model names are always the same pattern on your module names, the following code in **init**.py will probably work:

```
import os, glob

path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
modules = [os.path.basename(f)[:-3] for f in glob.glob(path + "/*.py")
           if not os.path.basename(f).startswith('_')]
stripped_path = os.path.relpath(path).replace('/', '.')
imports = {}
for module in modules:
    model_name = module.title().replace("_", "")
    imports[model_name] = getattr(__import__(stripped_path + "." + module, fromlist=[model_name]), model_name)
print(imports)
globals().update(imports)
```